# Trilinear interpolation in CUDA

Tags: cuda

I need to perform trilinear interpolation in CUDA. Here is the problem definition:

Given three vectors of points: `x[nx]`, `y[ny]`, `z[nz]` and a matrix of function values `func[nx][ny][nz]`, I want to find the function values at some random points between the ranges of `x`, `y` and `z`.

I can write my own interpolation kernel in CUDA, but I was wondering if there is one that already exists to do the job.

Thank you!

Comment: You can have a look at [Texture Memory section in CUDA programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#texture-memory). Specially *filtering mode* which enables you to have trilinear interpolation for a 3D texture.

Comment: Thanks, will look into the texture memory section for more info.

Comment: [npp](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/npp/index.html) can do various kinds of interpolation, but I'm not sure trilinear is one of them, and I'm not sure casting your vector space as a 3D image is sensible or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned by @Farzad, you can use texture filtering to perform trilinear interpolation in CUDA. The [simpleTexture3D](https://github.com/marwan-abdellah/GPU-Computing-SDK-4.2.9/tree/master/C/src/simpleTexture3D) sample provides a full example on how using it. However, as it stands, it may not be of immediate use since it involves the use of libraries like OpenGL and glut as well as other external dependencies like `cutil.h`.

Accordingly, I found it useful to reduce the above code to a "minimum sized" example showing the concept. As you will see, the code loads external data located in a file named `Bucky.raw` which I have "borrowed" from the github page linked to above.

The code below interpolates a cuboid of data to a regular Cartesian grid located in its central slice. If everything goes well, the image you will reconstruct is the one reported below.

[image]

The code is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream> 

#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuda.h>

typedef unsigned char uchar;

#define BLOCKSIZE 16

float w = 0.5;  // texture coordinate in z

/********************/
/* CUDA ERROR CHECK */
/********************/
#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
    if (code != cudaSuccess) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
        if (abort) { getchar(); exit(code); }
    }
}

typedef unsigned int  uint;
typedef unsigned char uchar;

texture<uchar, 3, cudaReadModeNormalizedFloat> tex;  // 3D texture

cudaArray *d_volumeArray = 0;

uint *d_output = NULL;
uint *h_output = NULL;

/************************************************/
/* TEXTURE-BASED TRILINEAR INTERPOLATION KERNEL */
/************************************************/
__global__ void
d_render(uint *d_output, uint imageW, uint imageH, float w)
{
    uint x = __umul24(blockIdx.x, blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x;
    uint y = __umul24(blockIdx.y, blockDim.y) + threadIdx.y;

    float u = x / (float) imageW;
    float v = y / (float) imageH;

    // read from 3D texture
    float voxel = tex3D(tex, u, v, w);

    if ((x < imageW) && (y < imageH)) {
        // write output color
        uint i = __umul24(y, imageW) + x;
        d_output[i] = voxel*255;
   }
}

void main() {

    int N = 32;
    int imageH = 512;
    int imageW = 512;

    const char* filename = "Bucky.raw";

    // --- Loading data from file
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (!fp) { fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file '%s'\n", filename); getchar(); return; }

    uchar *data = (uchar*)malloc(N*N*N*sizeof(uchar));
    size_t read = fread(data, 1, N*N*N, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    printf("Read '%s', %lu bytes\n", filename, read);

    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_output, imageH*imageW*sizeof(uint)));

    // --- Create 3D array
    const cudaExtent volumeSize = make_cudaExtent(N, N, N);

    cudaChannelFormatDesc channelDesc = cudaCreateChannelDesc<uchar>();
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc3DArray(&d_volumeArray, &channelDesc, volumeSize));

    // --- Copy data to 3D array (host to device)
    cudaMemcpy3DParms copyParams = {0};
    copyParams.srcPtr   = make_cudaPitchedPtr((void*)data, volumeSize.width*sizeof(uchar), volumeSize.width, volumeSize.height);
    copyParams.dstArray = d_volumeArray;
    copyParams.extent   = volumeSize;
    copyParams.kind     = cudaMemcpyHostToDevice;
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy3D(&copyParams));

    // --- Set texture parameters
    tex.normalized = true;                      // access with normalized texture coordinates
    tex.filterMode = cudaFilterModeLinear;      // linear interpolation
    tex.addressMode[0] = cudaAddressModeWrap;   // wrap texture coordinates
    tex.addressMode[1] = cudaAddressModeWrap;
    tex.addressMode[2] = cudaAddressModeWrap;

    // --- Bind array to 3D texture
    gpuErrchk(cudaBindTextureToArray(tex, d_volumeArray, channelDesc));

    // --- Launch the interpolation kernel
    const dim3 blockSize(BLOCKSIZE, BLOCKSIZE, 1);
    const dim3 gridSize(imageW / blockSize.x, imageH / blockSize.y);
    d_render<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(d_output, imageW, imageH, w);
    gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

    // --- Copy the interpolated data to host
    h_output = (uint*)malloc(imageW*imageH*sizeof(uint));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_output,d_output,imageW*imageH*sizeof(uint),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    std::ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("out_texture.dat", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    outfile.write((char*)h_output, imageW*imageH*sizeof(uint));
    outfile.close();

    getchar();

}
```

The code saves the results in a `out_texture.dat` in binary format. You can load binary data from Matlab according to

```
fd = fopen('out_texture.dat','r');
U = fread(fd,imageH*imageW,'unsigned int');
fclose(fd);
```