# Read from cudaBindTexture2D

Tags: c, cuda, nvidia

I have been trying store a 2D array in texture memory and read from it via cudaBindTexture2D 
but the value returned is 0, but I'm not sure if this is the right use of cudaBindTexture2D, and tex2D();

I made a pretty simple code to try it out :

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
texture<uint, cudaTextureType2D, cudaReadModeElementType> tex;
__global__ 
void texture2DTest(int *x){
*x = tex2D(tex,0,0);

}

void initTable(int textureTable[][9]){
int i=0;
int j=0;

for(i=0; i<10; i++){
    for(j=0; j<9; j++){
        textureTable[i][j]=0;
    }
}

textureTable[0][0] = 12;

}

int main (int argc, char ** argv){

int textureTable[10][9];

int *d_x;
int x=2;

size_t pitch;

initTable(textureTable);

cudaMalloc(&d_x, sizeof(int)); 
cudaMemcpy(d_x, &x, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

cudaMallocPitch( (void**)textureTable,&pitch, 9, 10);
cudaChannelFormatDesc desc = cudaCreateChannelDesc<uint>(); 
cudaBindTexture2D(NULL, tex, textureTable, desc, 9, 10, pitch) ;

texture2DTest<<<1,1>>>(d_x);

cudaThreadSynchronize();

cudaMemcpy(&x,d_x, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

printf(" \n %d \n",x);

cudaUnbindTexture(tex);

return 0;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: there are a variety of problems with this code (you don't do `cudaMallocPitch` on your host array that presumably contains your data, you are not initializing the data - you never call `initTable`, you are not doing proper cuda error checking...).  Perhaps you should study the cuda [pitch linear texture sample code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#pitch-linear-texture) which demonstrates usage of `cudaBindTexture2D`.  Also, here's a [fully worked simple 3D texturing example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25591045/cuda-3d-texture-interpolation).

Comment: Thank you for the reply, there is no error checking as I am trying to reproduce the problem, and I did forgot to call initTable in the sample code displayed here (i added it now). I do one cudaMallocPitch on line 45, is that part wrong ? thank you. I will however read the links you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few issues in the provided code.

- The device memory allocation using `cudaMallocPitch` is totally broken. You are trying to allocate device memory to a 2D array which is already allocated on the host.
  Trying to do so will result in memory corruption and undefined behavior. A separate pointer variable is required for device memory allocation and memory should be copied from host to device after allocation.
- The third argument of `cudaMallocPitch` expects width of memory in **bytes**; not elements.
- Textures can only be bound to device memory, so `cudaBindTexture` expects device memory pointer as input.

Fixing all of the above issues, your final `main` will look something like this:

```
int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{

int textureTable[10][9];

int *d_x;
int x = 2;

size_t pitch;

initTable(textureTable);

cudaMalloc(&d_x, sizeof(int)); 
cudaMemcpy(d_x, &x, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

int* d_textureTable; //Device texture table

//Allocate pitch linear memory to device texture table
cudaMallocPitch((void**)&d_textureTable,&pitch, 9 * sizeof(int), 10);

//Use Memcpy2D as the pitch of host and device memory may be different
cudaMemcpy2D(d_textureTable, pitch, textureTable, 9 * sizeof(int), 9 *sizeof(int), 10, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); 

cudaChannelFormatDesc desc = cudaCreateChannelDesc<uint>(); 
cudaBindTexture2D(NULL, tex, d_textureTable, desc, 9, 10, pitch) ;

texture2DTest<<<1,1>>>(d_x);

cudaThreadSynchronize();

cudaMemcpy(&x,d_x, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

printf(" \n %d \n",x);

cudaUnbindTexture(tex);
//Don't forget to free the allocated memory
cudaFree(d_textureTable);
cudaFree(d_x);
return 0;
}
```